# Why does a declared float calculate partially in integers?

Tags: c++, types, floating-point

volume of sphere is (4/3)(pi)(r^3) not (1)(pi)(r^3)

Why would it calculate (4/3) in integers?  I expect an explicitly declared float variable to calculate in float, not integers.

I have tried:

```
float v = float(4/3) * 3.14159 * pow(r, 3);
```

I double floated ya, and it still aint floating.

```
    cout << "  Calculate volume of sphere\n";
cout << "  __________________________\n";
float r;
cout << "  enter radius: ";
cin >> r;
float v = (4 / 3) * 3.14159 * pow(r, 3);
cout << "  volume = " << v << "\n";
cout << 4 / 3;  //  4/3 equals one?  Are you kidding me?
```

I expect 4/3 to equal 1.333, not 1.

Comment: change `4 / 3` to `4.0 / 3.0`

Comment: It is a basic property of C or C++ expressions; the type of an expression only depends on the operands to the expression.  Not on any outside context.  IMO It makes the language much easier to understand . I like knowing that `4/3` is always `1`  , not that `FOO(4/3)` might receive a different value to `BAR(4/3)`.

Comment: Because the integer calculation precedes the conversion to float.

Comment: Go with what's easiest to read until it has been proven to be too slow, but in order to support nightmarish stuff like e to the power of pi, `pow` can be an expensive function. `pow(r, 3)` will often be far, far more expensive than `r*r*r`. Since this program is doomed to be limited by user interaction, it won't matter, but when you write more mathematically intensive programs, be suspicious of `pow`

Comment: "Why does a declared float calculate partially in integers?"  Your question is _mu_.  It does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use integer numbers in a division, the compiler understands that it has to perform an integer division.

```
std::cout << 4 / 3;
```

That means that 4 divided 3 equals 1, and the rest can be obtained by doing `4 % 3` (that's the **modulo** operator)

If you want to get a floating point division, at least one of the operands has to be a floating point type. For example:

```
std::cout << 4.0 / 3;
```

Or:

```
std::cout << 4 / 3.0;
```

They can also be both floating points.

By doing this, you will be producing the expected output of 1.33333333333